# File Upload / Insert Image crashes browser

Tags: ckeditor, files, editor

Running the latest version 4.7.29 on Wordpress 4.9.2.

Using either CKEditor or TinyMCE if I attempt to "browse" the server for an image it locks up the tab and has to be killed. I use DUO Security and if this plugin is enabled it logs the session out immediately and prompts for re-authentication instead of locking up the tab. This loops indefinitely)

I have checked the paths on the file system and urls and all are ok. I have checked permissions and all are ok. I can see no errors in my access logs and get no debug information as it locks up the tab.

I'm at a complete loss with it.

Any help / suggestions welcome.

Variables in use:

```
**Settings - WordPress Integration:** https://abc.org/civicrm

$civicrm_root = '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'https://abc.org/' );


**CiviCRM Resource URL:** [civicrm.root]/
**Image Upload URL:** https://abc.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/
**Extension Resource URL:** https://abc.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/
```

Comment: Does it work if DUO Security is disabled?  Do you know what directory it is attempting to browse?  I've seen an image browser lock up when there were thousands of files in the directory it was attempting to load.

Comment: If DUO is disabled it loops indefinitely and locks up the browser. The actual URL being called is:  `plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php?cms=civicrm&type=images&CKEditor=crmUiId_1&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=en`